# how to create an opengl iphone app without a .nib file?

Tags: iphone, opengl

The subject says it all: How do I create an iPhone app with an OpenGL view without using a .nib file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course I find the answer right after posting, [here](http://madhukishore.blogspot.com/search/label/opengles_app_without_ib). It also includes a video tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

`File -> New project -> iPhoneOS Application -> OpenGL ES Application`

This will create all the code you need to get started.